# C# 'callback' from a second form

Tags: c#, .net, callback

I'm trying to callback from a second form in C#, however failing to do it, can anyone please help?

```
    // Form 1 (Main form)
    public void CallBack()
    {
         if (radioBox1.Checked)
         {
              RefreshForm("TRUE");
         }
         else if (radioBox2.Checked)
         {
              RefreshForm("FALSE");
         }
    }

    private void RefreshForm(string Options)
    {
         // Do something here
    }
```

Now for the 2nd form

```
    // Form 2 (Child Form)
    Form1 form1 = new form1();
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          form1.CallBack();
    }
```

Sadly the callback is not functioning, is there anything I've coded wrongly? Please help... Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't function because you're calling `CallBack` on a new instance of `Form1` that you just created, which is not the same instance as the main form.

You need to somehow reference the main form, e.g.:

```
(Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1).CallBack();
```

This is assuming the main form (Form1) is the first opened window of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Write down a message box in `CallBack()` method, it will always displayed.

On a new instance of Form1, neither `radioBox1` or `radioBox2` is checked, so call goes to `Callback` Method but nothing happened.

Comment: i think that is a typo mistake!

Answer (score 0):

The `callback` method is being called on `new instance` of the `Form1`, rather the one you need to.

Since you are using a MDI Interface, you can update the Method as :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      (this.MdiParent as Form1).CallBack();
}
```